# Insertion sort function acts weird C++

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, vector, insertion-sort

I want to make a function to sort random numbers (generated using another function) and I've been trying to do that for some time, but nothing worked. Now I have a problem that sometimes my program compiles without any problems and sometimes it says "vector subscript out of range" and even if it compiles properly it inserts some numbers in the wrong order (especially when the next number to sort is smaller than the previous one). I've tried to use debugger and to figure out what's wrong but for me everything seems fine. Could you be so kind and help me? Thank you very much.

```
std::vector <int> insertion_sort(std::vector <int> generated)
{
    using namespace std;
    bool emplaced = false;
    vector <int> buffor(1);

    buffor[0] = generated[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < generated.size(); i++)
    {
        emplaced = false;

        if (generated[i] >= buffor[i-1])
        {
            buffor.push_back(generated[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            int x = 2;
            while (((i - x) > -1))
            {
                if (emplaced == true)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if ((i - x) == 0)
                {
                    buffor.emplace(buffor.begin(), generated[i]);
                    emplaced = true;
                }

                if (generated[i] < bufor[i - x])
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    buffor.emplace(buffor.begin() + (i-x), generated[i]);
                    emplaced == true;
                }

                x++;
            }
        }

    }

    return buffor;
}
```

Comment: 1) "_vector subscript out of range_" Is not compilation error. It's, most likely, failed runtime assertion. 2) Please provide [mcve]. 3) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: BTW, why not use `std::sort` ?

Comment: I did, but all I've noticed is that the program has problem with sorting numbers smaller than those already sorted (those in buffor vector). I have to create my own function as a exercise for my IT studies.  

For example if the input (vector of integers) is:  96 99 24 46 58 40 78 24  
it shows:  78 78 46 78 46 78 24 78 46 78 24 96 99 58 40 24  

But if the input is : 58 49 82 72 61 87 74 21  
then I get "vector subscript out of range"

Comment: *the input (vector of integers) is: 96 99 24 46 58 40 78 24 it shows: 78 78 46 78 46 78 24 78 46 78 24 96 99 58 40 24* : Is this an expected result ??

Comment: The expected result is 24 24 40 46 58 78 96 99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertion sort is a simple sorting algorithm and can be implemented by more compact 
 and straightforward code like as follows:

[**DEMO is here.**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Irmt3cCbgiwsdZM3)

```
std::vector<int> insertion_sort(const std::vector<int>& generated)
{
    auto shifted(generated);

    for (std::size_t j = 1; j < shifted.size(); ++j) 
    {
        const auto temp = shifted[j];

        if(shifted[j-1] > temp)
        {
            int i = j;

            do{
                shifted[i] = shifted[i-1];
                --i;
            } while(i > 0 && shifted[i-1] > temp);

            shifted[i]=temp;
        }
    }

    return shifted;    
}
```

Comment: If the goal is to do it in a compact and straightforward way, it would be better to use `emplace()` with the appropriate iterator for the insertion position and let `vector` do the shifting. And you can use `std::find_if` to find the appropriate iterator for the insertion point. Or better yet, use a binary search.

Comment: @TypeIA thx a lot.I think so too. Since this is an IT studies, here I avoid using helper algorithms like `std::find_if` or binary search.